# get_relationship method call returns a single record when two are expected

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have a defined one to many relationship between accounts and analysis, sugar link name is accounts_analysis_1. Using API V4.1 I want to retrieve all analysis ids where accounts id is equal for example to this fixed id `31381e50-2eff-bc0f-0636-5b9a71e60551`

In order to achieve, I have tried the following logic but I only get one result and I expect two

```
$relationshipParameters = (object)[
    'moduleName' => 'Accounts',
    'moduleId' => '31381e50-2eff-bc0f-0636-5b9a71e60551',
    'linkFieldName' => 'accounts_analysis_1',
    'relatedModuleQuery' => '',
    'relatedFields' => ['id'],
    'relatedModuleLinkNameToFieldsArray' => []
];

$results = $this->restClient->getRelationships(
    $relationshipParameters->moduleName,
    $relationshipParameters->moduleId,
    $relationshipParameters->linkFieldName,
    $relationshipParameters->relatedModuleQuery,
    $relationshipParameters->relatedFields
);
```

the call to `$this->restClient->getRelationships` is just a wrapper to the API Method [get_relationships](https://docs.suitecrm.com/developer/appendix-b-api-methods/)

This is the result I get in JSON format, here I expect two results but I am getting one. Even when the wrapper call to `get_relationships` api method set limit to 200 by default

```
{
    "entry_list": [
        {
            "id": "45e93fff-63d0-e6e5-a55d-5d5a8c73f7fe",
            "module_name": "analysis",
            "name_value_list": { "id": { "name": "id", "value": "45e93fff-63d0-e6e5-a55d-5d5a8c73f7fe" } }
        }
    ],
    "relationship_list": []
}
```

In summary, I try to reproduce the following SQL query, which returns me two ids

```
select accounts_analysis_1_c.accounts_analysis_1analysis_idb from accounts_analysis_1_c where accounts_analysis_1accounts_ida = '31381e50-2eff-bc0f-0636-5b9a71e60551';
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to verify it by using the below query:

```
select accounts_analysis_1_c.accounts_analysis_1analysis_idb from accounts_analysis_1_c where accounts_analysis_1accounts_ida = '31381e50-2eff-bc0f-0636-5b9a71e60551' and deleted = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked in the past with getting related contacts to an account and following code worked fine for me:

```
$get_relationships_parameters = array(
    'session' => $session_id,
    'module_name' => 'Accounts',
    'module_id' => '2a2ecece-ac87-55c7-2f42-5d5a6ce70fe4',
    'link_field_name' => 'contacts',
    'related_module_query' => "",
    'related_fields' => array(
        'id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name'
    ),
    'related_module_link_name_to_fields_array' => array(
        array(
        ),
    ),
    'deleted'=> 0,
    'order_by' => '',
    'offset' => 0,
    'limit' => 200,
);
```

Modify it according to your need and for further help, you can read details from [here](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.9/Integration/Web_Services/v1_-_v4.1/Methods/get_relationships/)